# Display Full Name Instead of Username in LoginName Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

The LoginName control displays the Username. I would like to display the Full Name of the user logged in rather than the Username. Below is my code. I cannot seem to access the LoginName control in code behind. I am wondering if it because the control is in .

ASPX Page:

```
<asp:loginview id="HeadLoginView" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        [ <a id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" href="login">Log In</a> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <span class="bold">
            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
        </span>! [
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" 
            LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/home"
            LogoutText="Log Out" />
        ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:loginview>
```

Please post code behind examples in C# if possible...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to figure out a short cut:

```
LoginName loginName = HeadLoginView.FindControl("HeadLoginName") as LoginName;

        if (loginName != null && session != null)
        {
            loginName.FormatString = "Full Name";
        }
```

This finds the LoginName control within the LoginView, then hijacks the value by setting FormatString. I wish there was a more elegant way of doing this. If anyone knows, please send it my way.

Answer (score 0):

The [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx) control seems somewhat automatic in its behaviour.  You may want to switch to using something different and take a different kind of control over the experience...

You might try the [**Login control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) instead, to see if it allows for the flexbility you require.  For example its .[UserName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.username.aspx) is both read/write.

```
Login1.UserName = "MY REAL NAME";
```

Apparently it supports many features through declarative syntax too.

```
<asp:Login
    AccessKey="string"
    BackColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderPadding="integer"
    BorderStyle="NotSet|None|Dotted|Dashed|Solid|Double|Groove|Ridge|
        Inset|Outset"
    BorderWidth="size"
    CreateUserIconUrl="uri"
    CreateUserText="string"
    CreateUserUrl="uri"
    CssClass="string"
    DestinationPageUrl="uri"
    DisplayRememberMe="True|False"
    Enabled="True|False"
    EnableTheming="True|False"
    EnableViewState="True|False"
    FailureAction="Refresh|RedirectToLoginPage"
    FailureText="string"
    Font-Bold="True|False"
    Font-Italic="True|False"
    Font-Names="string"
    Font-Overline="True|False"
    Font-Size="string|Smaller|Larger|XX-Small|X-Small|Small|Medium|
               Large|X-Large|XX-Large"
    Font-Strikeout="True|False"
    Font-Underline="True|False"
    ForeColor="color name|#dddddd"
    Height="size"
    HelpPageIconUrl="uri"
    HelpPageText="string"
    HelpPageUrl="uri"
    ID="string"
    InstructionText="string"
    LoginButtonImageUrl="uri"
    LoginButtonText="string"
    LoginButtonType="Button|Image|Link"
    MembershipProvider="string"
    OnAuthenticate="Authenticate event handler"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
    OnInit="Init event handler"
    OnLoad="Load event handler"
    OnLoggedIn="LoggedIn event handler"
    OnLoggingIn="LoggingIn event handler"
    OnLoginError="LoginError event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
    OnUnload="Unload event handler"
    Orientation="Horizontal|Vertical"
    PasswordLabelText="string"
    PasswordRecoveryIconUrl="uri"
    PasswordRecoveryText="string"
    PasswordRecoveryUrl="uri"
    PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="string"
    RememberMeSet="True|False"
    RememberMeText="string"
    runat="server"
    SkinID="string"
    Style="string"
    TabIndex="integer"
    TextLayout="TextOnLeft|TextOnTop"
    TitleText="string"
    ToolTip="string"
    UserName="string"
    UserNameLabelText="string"
    UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="string"
    Visible="True|False"
    VisibleWhenLoggedIn="True|False"
    Width="size"
>
        <CheckBoxStyle />
        <FailureTextStyle />
        <HyperLinkStyle />
        <InstructionTextStyle />
        <LabelStyle />
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <LoginButtonStyle />
        <TextBoxStyle />
        <TitleTextStyle />
        <ValidatorTextStyle />
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: I am using the LoginView control with a LoginName control embedded. The issue is that this control displays only a Username and not a friendly full name or first name of the user.

Comment: I am pretty sure the Login control is for authentication (input) and not display. Setting the Username property sets the value for which you want to send to the server for authentication. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's fair. You might try a different kind of login control, even a 3rd-party one might provide some different features.  The ASP.NET Login control I mentioned seems accessible from the code-behind and likely you won't have the same problem of inaccessible username field for replacement of the username with a full name, unless I'm not understanding the question properly.

Comment: Re: Auth: you're right about the field's intention; however you have to call the authentication method for the Login control, which gives you the opportunity to switch up logic at that point, e.g. swap out the username, etc. I don't know if you plan to keep both full name and username in play at the same time, but you can manage it with custom programming and page storage, or subclassing a control, etc.