# How to display full name instead of username using session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to web development and .NET too. I have a website written in ASP.NET using C#. How should I display full name of the current user instead of username using sessions? Please help me. Here is the code.

Code behind login page:-

```
Session["username"] = txt_un.Text.Trim().ToString();
```

Code behind userprofile page:-

```
string str = "select fullname from userprofile where username=@username";

Label4.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
```

The problem is that fullname is not present on the login page. It is present in userprofile page. How to display fullname on the userprofile page after user click on login button?User is using his registration_id as username. But I don't want to display registration_id,I want to display fullname of the user.Pls give me answer in detail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897894/display-full-name-instead-of-username-in-loginname-control?rq=1

Comment: I created a UserInfo class which contained the username, group, and some other identify information I needed. I created an instance for the user and saved it in their session when they logged in. I also added some methods for easily saving it into the session state and pulling it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get first name, Whenever you login in your app with this select query and `ExecuteScalar`.

```
string str = "select fullname from userprofile where username=@username";
```

Then You need to store the first name into a session

```
Session[firstName]=Query return value
```

And finally you can give

```
if(Session[firstName]!=null)
{
Label4.Text=Session[firstName].ToString()
}
```

Comment: How to write query for ExecuteScalar()? How to write exact code? Still I am not getting. Pls explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand clearly what you need but somehow you need user's full name to show some where using username,

**Here one simple function that will return you the full name.**

I assume you know how to connect your webpage to the SQL Server and all the functions

```
public string GetFullName(string username)
{
    string query = "select fullname from userprofile where username ='" + staffID + "'";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            return reader["fullname"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Error_Message_Session"] = ex;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", false);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return "-";
}
```

The function that i used here is from my own project, this is how i get the full name by his username, similarly i had the same problem so i did this, just a simple static function

Comment: Why you used `ExecuteReader();` ? `ExecuteScalar` is better that.

Comment: Yes, i know but SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() can be used only when the result have just one row and one column, but i used the same function to other queries with slightly alternations, so i am lil lazy one that